# Is there anyway to load up a asp.net page object and render its contents to string from a console application?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use aspx pages as an email templates. There will likely be a bunch of objects on the page which will be used as replacements in the html. Because it's an aspx page I'll be able to use databinding, repeaters, etc. At run time, I want to be able to instantiate the aspx page from its path, pass in a bunch of properties, and then get the rendered result of the page and email it. This seems pretty straightforward from a asp.net website (maybe using BuildManager or Server.Execute.) However, I want to be able to use the same templates via a console application by just loading up a page object from its filepath. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could host your own webserver. Like the [Cassini webserver](http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/cassini).

In my own application (a Windows-based Desktop-CMS), I include a web server, too (non-Cassini). It works very well, also it does not serve ASP.NET but plain, HTML.

As I did some research back then, I first wanted to use the Cassini, too, but at some point, I found out that too much user privileges were required to run it successfully; this may not be an issue to you, but keeping this in mind and try to run it early with the permissions of the later user, might be a good idea.

Comment: hrm i think it's just too much overhead to process an aspx page... i think maybe aspx pages are the wrong approach, i really just need conditionals and loops...

Comment: In another project, I implemented something similar: HTML pages withC# code blocks inside `<$` and `$>`, similar to ASP.NET. I dynamically compiled the C# code and executed it. Maybe this would be enough, for you too? (This approach does not allow you to unload from the app-domain, so it is only suitable if you have a small/constant number of scripts to compile).

Comment: If you need some code examples, just tell me, I can take a look, tomorrow in the office.

Comment: yea, that's actually what i'd like to do, but it's def overkill for this project. i'm just going do some string replacing :p